# SQL query add new column if two existing columns matches and add value from another column

Tags: mysql, sql

Table *1* columns are **(current state)**

```
=======================================================
record_id |  ad_id | gender | gender_view | time_entry
=======================================================
1         |   1    |  male  |     45      | 1557072000
2         |   1    | female |     88      | 1557072000
```

Table *2* columns are **(current state)**

```
=====================
ad_id | submitted_by
=====================
1     |   1
```

After matching the **ad_id** of table 1 and table 2 , table 1 will have new column **submitted_by**. The new column submitted_by in table 1 will take submitted_by value from table 2.

Table **1** columns  **(expected state)**

```
====================================================================
record_id |  ad_id | gender | gender_view | time_entry | submitted_by 
====================================================================
1         |   1    |  male  |     45      | 1557072000 |   1
2         |   1    | female |     88      | 1557072000 |   1
```

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`.  `ON`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff what if it not match?

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: You seem to be missing basic SQL understanding. I'm not even sure if you're asking how to retrieve data, or if you actually want to change the underlying table. Your question to Gordon should be answered by your example data (i.e., you've only shown what you want when there is a match, not when there's not). You just haven't put enough information in this question to be sure what needs answering.

Comment: _"table 1 will have new column submitted_by which will hold value related to ad_id"_ . To be clear, the new column `submitted_by` in table 1 will take `submitted_by` value or `ad_id` value from table 2? I assume it will take `submitted_by` value from table 2 but I'm just making sure

Comment: @tcadidot0 the new column submitted_by in table 1 will take submitted_by value  from table 2.

Answer (score 0):

A simple `LEFT JOIN` with `ON T2.ad_id = T1.ad_id`, will return your expected result:

```
SELECT T1.record_id,
       T1.ad_id,
       T1.gender,
       T1.gender_view,
       T1.time_entry
       COALESCE(T2.submitted_by, 0) submitted_by
FROM Table1 T1
LEFT JOIN Table2 T2 ON T2.ad_id = T1.ad_id
```

Comment: @JhonDoe Is my answer helpful?

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.*,t2.submitted_by 
from table1 t1 
inner join table2 t2 on t1.ad_id = t2.ad_id
```